# Differences: creating sql database in visual studio & sql sever 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssms, sql-server-2008

I usually use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for system development and I always use the built-in SQL Server Express in Visual Studio to create and manage a database.

Currently, I'm learning Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to create and manage a database.

I got some questions here:

1. What is the differences of the database in built-in sql server in Visual Studio & SQL Server Management Studio? Such as features and limitations.
2. Will it be better to create and manage database in SQL Server Management Studio instead of the built-in visual studio database?
3. I encounter a problem which is unable to upload my built-in Visual Studio SQL database to the web server in the past. So is creating database in SQL Server Management Studio much ideal for uploading database file to web server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Te latest versions of SSMS say "powered by Visual Studio" so your question could be moot. I think using SSMS gets you slightly closer to the database server itself -- which if you are doing admin too may be a good thing.